# List of preinstalled Python packages in Yosemite?

Tags: macos, python

I have installed many python packages via `sudo pip install` and some of them have messed up the system by overwriting or updating preloaded python packages. Now I want to revert all the damage done and install my own packages only in a `virtualenv`. Is there any way I can obtain a list of python packages, preferably with their version, that comes with a clean Yosemite?

Comment: There are approximately 5000 files in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib and nothing in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages - do you have any other directories in $PYTHONPATH and/or by printing sys.path from the interpreter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is the list for Yosemite:

```
MODULES = \
    setuptools-1.1.6 \
    altgraph-0.10.2 \
    modulegraph-0.10.4 \
    macholib-1.5.1 \
    bdist_mpkg-0.5.0 \
    py2app-0.7.3 \
    numpy-1.8.0rc1 \
    xattr-0.6.4 \
    bonjour-py-0.3 \
    scipy-0.13.0b1 \
    pytz-2013.7 \
    six-1.4.1 \
    python-dateutil-1.5 \
    pyparsing-2.0.1 \
    matplotlib-1.3.1 \
    pyOpenSSL-0.13.1
```

Which is from:
https://opensource.apple.com/source/python_modules/python_modules-40/2.7.inc.auto.html

And for Mojave (most recent as of posting):

```
MODULES = \
    setuptools-18.5 \
    altgraph-0.10.2 \
    modulegraph-0.10.4 \
    macholib-1.5.1 \
    bdist_mpkg-0.5.0 \
    py2app-0.7.3 \
    numpy-1.8.0rc1 \
    xattr-0.6.4 \
    bonjour-py-0.3 \
    scipy-0.13.0b1 \
    pytz-2013.7 \
    six-1.4.1 \
    python-dateutil-1.5 \
    pyparsing-2.0.1 \
    matplotlib-1.3.1 \
    pyOpenSSL-0.13.1
```

Which is from:
https://opensource.apple.com/source/python_modules/python_modules-46.200.1/2.7.inc.auto.html